# Select image by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you select an image based on id using jQuery? Because when I tried it, it didn't work. Is this the correct way? Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imageID").click(function (){
        $("#imageID").addClass("className");
    });    
});
```

Comment: Yes it is a correct way..

Comment: Show us your html though, and i hope that it is not dyanamically genrated image?

Comment: If your image is dynamically generated, you'll have to use something like `$(body).on('click', 'img', function(){ $(this).addClass("className"); });`

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because the element is not inside the DOM when you bind the event. Then you could try to bind with jquery using `on` function and binding the event to `body` for instance:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("body").on("click", "#imageID", function (){
         $(e.target).addClass("className");
     });   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check duplicate id's.

Better way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imageID").on('click', function (){
        $(this).addClass("className");
    });
});
```

Also, it add new classname only to clicked image, not to all images, so this is right way.

Your problem may occures because you have thow or more tags with `#imageID` id.

So, more better way is using js-* classes:

```
<img src="/images/img.png" class="js-my-image" alt="">
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".js-my-image").on('click', function (){
        $(this).addClass("className");
    });
});
```

If image is added after page loads, right code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.js-my-image', function (){
        $(this).addClass("className");
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".js-my-image").live('click', function (){
        $(this).addClass("className");
    });
});
```